# Is it possible to have a nonlexicographic order

Tags: java, lexicographic

I searched it up but I couldn't find anything since I don't know the actual name to it. Is it possible to have a nonlexicographic order for example the Alphabet comes first before then numbers then symbols?

I know in java compareTo statement does it lexigraphic so is there a non-lexicographic order?

Comment: You can define a custom comparator to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sorting or creating sorted collections, you can always specify your own instance of the object's [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). That way you can alter the ordering of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own compareTo function for classes so you can order your objects anyway you want.